# Let $\varphi:G \to K$ be an epimorphism. Let $J \triangleleft K$. Prove there exists a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H \cong K/J$.

Tags: group-theory

Let $\varphi:G \to K$ be an epimorphism. Let $J \triangleleft K$. Prove there exists a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H \cong K/J$.

By definition, an epimorphism has the following property: If $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $g_ 1 \circ g_1 = g_2 \circ \varphi$, then $g_1=g_2$. To prove this

1. I need to find a map $\phi: G \to K/J$ and prove that it is epimorphism.
2. Then apply the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms and get $G/ker \phi \cong K/J$
3. Then by a property of the fundamental theorem that $ker \phi=J$.

Let $\pi: K \to K/J$, and $\phi=\pi \circ \varphi$.

If $\pi, \varphi$ is an epimorphism

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g_1 \circ \phi=g_2 \circ \phi &\Rightarrow g_1 \circ (\pi \circ \varphi)=g_2 \circ (\pi \circ \varphi) \\
& \Rightarrow (g_1 \circ \pi) \circ \varphi=(g_2 \circ \pi) \circ \varphi \\
& \Rightarrow h_1 \circ \varphi=h_2 \circ \varphi \\
& \Rightarrow h_1 =h_2 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

Now in the proof I am assuming that $\pi$ is an epimorphism. How do I should that?

Comment: Your definition of epimorphism is wrong: what you wrote is *monomorphism*. Epimorphism means that for all $\;k\in K\;$ there exists $\;g\in G\;$ s.t. $\;\phi g=h\;$

Comment: Moreover, the result *does not hold* for monomorphisms. Take $G=\langle1\rangle$... So, the issue here is that you need to get your definitions correct! (I do not mean for posting here, I just mean in general...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, an epimorphism has the following property: If $g_1,g_2\in G$ and $g_ 1 \circ g_1 = g_2 \circ \varphi$, then $g_1=g_2$. To prove this

1. I need to find a map $\phi: G \to K/J$ and prove that it is epimorphism.
2. Then apply the fundamental theorem on homomorphisms and get $G/ker
       \phi \cong K/J$
3. Then by a property of the fundamental theorem that $ker \phi=H$.

Let $\pi: K \to K/J$, and $\phi=\pi \circ \varphi$. To proof that $\phi$ is an epimorphism we need to first show that $\pi$ is an epimorphism.

From equivalence class is not empty, we have that $$\forall [x]_J \in K/J: \exists x \in K: x \in [x]_J$$ So $\pi$ is surjective. (i.e. $\pi$ is an epimorphism).

Now we can show that $\phi$ is an epimorphism. If $\pi, \varphi$ are epimorphisms, then $g_1,g_2 \in G$

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
g_1 \circ \phi=g_2 \circ \phi & \Rightarrow g_1 \circ (\pi \circ \varphi)=g_2 \circ (\pi \circ \varphi) \\
& \Rightarrow g_1 \circ \pi \circ \varphi=g_2 \circ \pi \circ \varphi \\
& \Rightarrow g_1 \circ \pi=g_2 \circ \pi \\
& \Rightarrow g_1 =g_2 \\
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

So with what I stated above the proof of $\phi$ being an epimorphism, then there exists a normal subgroup $H$ of $G$ such that $G/H \cong K/J$.

Comment: As has been mentioned already in this thread, your definition of "epimorphism" is wrong. You are saying "surjective", but yuor definition is "injective". Indeed, you say "$g_1\circ\phi=g_2\circ\phi\Rightarrow g_1=g_2$", but just take $g_1=1$ and $g_2\in J\setminus \{1\}$. Please, go back to your book and re-write the question using the *correct* definition.

Comment: I went to the book and it stated that epimorphism have right cancelation.

Comment: This is not the definition of "right cancellation" - this is actually left cancellation! Epimorphisms are surjective: a function $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is surjective if for all $y\in Y$ there exists some $x\in X$ such that $f(x)=y$. You might find this question helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/139209/surjective-maps-and-right-cancellation

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Compose with the quotient map $K\to K/J$.

Comment: I have updated my question with your hint